# Static tab in teams custom app not showing loading the url added in contenturl

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have just created a teams app that has a static tab in which I've added a url for a sample page created in Flask which is running on ngrok. But when I install the tab and add it to a team, the loading icon starts loading and then says "There was a problem reaching this app". I've also tried adding a public website's URL in it and got the same result.

Comment: Are you using the loadingIndicator setting?

Comment: Is there any console error you are getting?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow no I'm not.

Comment: Have you referenced the Teams JS SDK in your code, and called the Initialize() method?

Comment: There were some unneeded keys in the manifest file. Removing them worked for me.